# How to reinstall user auth modules in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I inherited a Laravel project in which there doesn't appear to be a `app/User.php` file or any migration scripts related to the creation of `user` tables for the database.  This project was initially used to create a simple REST API end point to write records to a single table without authentication.

**Is there a simple command I can run to re-introduce the Laravel user components?**  My goal is to install Laravel Passport with OAuth2 support, but it seems to depend on the existence of user modules.

Answer (score 1):

you can follow the instruction in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#introduction

> Want to get started fast? Install the laravel/ui Composer package and
>   run php artisan ui vue --auth in a fresh Laravel application. After
>   migrating your database, navigate your browser to
>   http://your-app.test/register or any other URL that is assigned to
>   your application. These commands will take care of scaffolding your
>   entire authentication system!

Comment: Can i do this without starting a new laravel application? I want to continue based on this project I've inherited.  I also don't need the ui/vue part because this is a rest api that will use passport for oauth2 authentication

Comment: it really depends on what is in your project - it shouldn't  break anything but better backup first before trying it